# I need a dynamic collection type that exposes the array

Tags: c#

I need a collection type that will store everything in an array in the order it was added, it needs dynamically increase in size, and it needs to expose the array as a public field/property for reading.

I have determined that the c# List.ToArray() is too expensive for my purposes.

Is there a collection type that fits my requirements? If not, can you refer me to a custom class that will allow me to do this?

Edit: To add more info, I have benchmarked .ToArray() for people asking, and the purpose of this is to send the struct array to the graphics card so it can render vertices. So if you are wondering why I need the array, that is why.

Edit2: the buffer stays on the CPU and is just sent to GPU every frame, because it change often, but it's size does not change often.

Comment: You *think* you need to expose the array. Can you explain why you think this is the case?  Also, have you benchmarked and *proven* that `ToArray()` is too slow, or are you just guessing?

Comment: Are you aware that dynamically changing in size pretty much means that the data structure ***is not*** an array?  So to *expose the array* will actually mean converting back to a non-dynamic structure?

Comment: Do you need a generic collection? What will be the number of items in the collection? Why do you need such a structure?

Comment: Any old dynamic array class implementation should work. They're trivial to write. Then you can expose the internal array. But there's a reason this is not usually done. It's bad design.

Comment: @MatBailie `List<T>` uses a `T[]` to store the data, doesn't it?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The `ToArray()` implementation in `List<T>` actually copies the whole array into a new array.

Comment: @hatchet Thanks guys. I deleted my comment. I knew there was a special case, but I forgot that it did an array copy.  Still, the OP needs to be sure about his assumptions, and explaining why `List<T>` won't work would certainly help.

Comment: @BlazArt Why don't you use a classical array if it has to be sent to graphics card? Graphics card cannot handle resizing buffer as easily... You have to destroy it and recreate it (which is not efficient at all).

Comment: I'm a little confused why a single array copy via ToArray is too expensive, but the 10 or 20 array copies that happen while the List is built (when it has to grow) is ok. Why not just create an array in the first place? If you access the List's array directly, be aware that there are usually many empty unused elements at the end (when count is less than capacity).

Comment: @hatchet You can set the capacity when you create the list with `new List<T>(int)` which removes this problem of multiple memory allocations and copies.

Comment: @Blaz Art: if you need send it to a GPU, use a classic Array and unsafe code *pointer, if this is possible in your case.

Comment: about the "in the order it was added" maybe Stack<T>.

Comment: @CédricBignon - then given his need, why even use List? Why not just use an array and be done with it.

Comment: @hatchet because the array size is likely to not grow very often. Almost every frame the array will be the same size so ToArray is needlessly expensive. But at the same time, I need the array to have the ability to grow, so I can't use a normal array.

Comment: @BlazArt What is the content of your collection? How do you handle buffer resizing on the graphics card?

Comment: @CédricBignon The content is a struct with some floats. The buffer is never on the graphics card, the buffer IS the array, and the array is sent to the grapics card every frame.

Comment: _"it needs to expose the array as a public property for reading"_ [CA1819: Properties should not return arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx)

Comment: @TimSchmelter it can be a public field too, does not matter, I just need to get the array reference somehow.

Comment: @BlazArt If the size does not change often, use an array.

Comment: @CédricBignon But it needs be able to grow.......

Comment: @BlazArt You have the method [Array.Resize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx). If you need to keep the data in it. Or create a new array if you don't need the previous data.

Comment: @CédricBignon Array.Resize() is probably a good solution for me. THanks. If you make an answer ill vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second edit to your post gives the solution.

Given the following requirements and constraints:

- The collection must provide a fast access the (underlying) array because its used to for dynamic usage with a GPU (access every frame)
- It's content is often modified but not its size.
- It's sometimes resized (not often)

The first and last requirements makes me think an array is still the best solution in your case (whereas a List is interesting in case of frequent resizing (thanks to its capacity property)).

Now, to "resize" your array you have two possibilities:

1. [`Array.Resize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) if you need to keep the data from the previous array.
2. Creating a new array if you don't need the previous data

Answer (score 0):

> I need a collection type that will store everything in an array in the
>   order it was added, it needs dynamically increase in size, and it
>   needs to expose the array as a public property for reading.

You can simply use `List<object>` and where you need array, use its `ToArray(..)` call.

**EDIT**

If for some reason `ToArray(..)` is  not good for you ("too expensive"), you can use the same object to access it via index. If that is actual your requirement.

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

*EDIT*

Considering that you're talking about *GPU* interaction, so you have very big arrays of vertices with 3D data, I would suggest to use a simple `Array` provided by `C#` and use unsafe code with a *pointer, **if this is possible** in your case (I'm not aware of the signature of the calling methods on *GPU* side).

So there will no any *dynamic* allocation, that has to be handled by your code on request.

Comment: "List.ToArray() is too expensive for my purposes."

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I don't know what that "too expensive" means here. Edited answer, by the way.

Comment: @Tigran: "Too expensive" means that it costs too much in terms of cpu and/or memory for OP. `ToArray` creates a new collection, it does not just "expose  the array as property".

Comment: @TimSchmelter: yes, but if *he need that*, there is no other option. The question is: does he *really* need it? So added edited answer.

Comment: @Tigran Actually there is. Reflection.

Comment: @Tigran: Yes, i also think that he should just use a `List<T>`. It stores everything in an array in the order it was added, it increases dynamically  in size and it  can be used like an array, so +1. So the only problem is that it's mutable, if that is a problem at all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter He wants to send it to a graphics card, so it's useless.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: it's not useless, it just another data structure. GPU is a *destination* of the data, the source can be List<T> too. Considering that he is talking about vertices, calling ToArray() or creating an array in any other way would double the memory. So *that* is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    private FieldInfo _finfo = 
         typeof(List<T>)
         .GetField("_items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    public T[] Items
    {
        get
        { 
            return (T[])_finfo.GetValue(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This just has Bad Idea (TM) written all over it. Clever though, so I'm not going to downvote.

Comment: Ohhh, That's a very very bad thing!

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Do you mean implementation detail dependant? Yes, true. But I'm not going to write a whole IList implementation. Feel free to, though.

Comment: @CédricBignon Read my previous comment.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I saw it. I think the best choice for us is to understand why the OP wants such a structure (number of elements, ...).

Comment: @CédricBignon It seems to be just about sending it to a graphics card.

Comment: If there is a change in the internal representation, at least this will break immediately. _items can be static.

Comment: @Govert I know it does, but it works right now, and I think a few other methods depend on it being _items, so I doubt it'll change. I concur though, it's a bad idea.

Comment: Using the private _items array from the list class is troubling, I have tried this with No success. Because of the way the List class works, there is unfilled structs in the array sometimes, and it does not organize them at the end of the array like you would expect, so when I try to pull the relevant data from the array by just using the beginning of the array and an amount, I pick up some blank data, which screws everything.

Comment: @BlazArt - unless you write your own List<T> class that grows by one element at a time (which would be really slow), this is just a fact of life: being able to grow means having unused space at the end whenever count < capacity.

Comment: @hatchet I know that, the problem with List particularly is that it seems to put it's unused space in unexpected spots. I believe I made that clear in the above comment.

Comment: @BlazArt - it doesn't put unused space in unexpected places. Unused space in a List<T> is always at the end. List<T> is very simple. It is almost literally just an array and a count. When an element is added and count == capacity, a new, bigger array is created, and the old copied to the new. It doesn't have holes. When an element is deleted, all elements to the right are copied left by one.

Comment: @nSEI - I mean the fact that your method would break _immediately_ in case of implementation change is a good thing. You're less likely to get mysterious behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The single copy won't cost you too much unless the array is massive, like Large Object Heap massive. The only case where this is not true is if you're attempting to write a game for Windows Phone or Xbox 360, where garbage collection is blocking and takes a very long time.

In that case, I'd recommend creating a static array much larger than you'd ever need and pass that to the GPU with the proper length.

If you gave us some more details, I could make some more suggestions about how to avoid extra overhead. If you're fine with using `unsafe`, I'd recommend looking into memory mapping your buffer and working directly with the pointer it gives you. You won't be able to resize it without reallocating the buffer, however, so make sure it's large enough to begin with.

Example, with OpenGL:

```
unsafe
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myBuffer);
    float* bufferPtr = (float*)glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);

    // Update the buffer here, reading and writing to the pointer.

    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
}
```

I'm not quite as familiar with Direct3D, so I can't give you example code, but it'll be something very similar.

Comment: the buffer lives on the CPU and is sent to GPU every frame. There is also multiple buffers... I really need a class collection type that does what I said it should do. I don't believe your suggestion helps me.

Comment: @BlazArt multiple buffers can be mapped simultaneously in both OpenGL and DirectX. And if you have a copy that lives in regular system memory, you already have 2 copies of the data. What I'm suggesting is that you have all of your data live on the GPU and use memory-mapping to access it CPU side. This is almost certainly going to be significantly more efficient (both in time and memory usage) than what you're asking for.

Comment: After reading the comments on your question, this is definitely premature optimization. The time spent sending data over the PCI-e bus is going to be SIGNIFICANTLY greater than a single memory copy from `ToArray()`, especially if you're doing it every frame.